# Understanding of transition amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, path-integral

In QFT, suppose we have state at initial position and time $x_i$ and $t_i$ respectively and by corresponding state is $|x_i;t_i\rangle$.

Then, according to most textbooks, transition amplitude when given initial state transists to final state $|x_f;t_f\rangle$ is $\langle x_f;t_f|x_i;t_i\rangle$.
In this situation, using analogy with statistical interpretation of normal quantum mechanics, can I interprete that ket vector as

$$|x_i,t_i\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \int_{t_i}^{\infty}dt C(x,t) |x;t\rangle$$

Where $C(x,t)$ is coefficient-like quantity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, those kets and bras have dirac orthogonality in x,t separately.